# Create new sql.js database using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, sql.js

I'm trying to migrate my js code into typescript. One of the libs I use is sql.js. Successfully installed corresponding typing for it, but am blocked with creation of the database.

How it was in JS:

```
  var db = new SQL.Database();
  db.run('CREATE TABLE snapshots (dateTime LONGINT, snapshot BLOB)');
```

There is no parameterless constructor in sql.js/index.d.ts file:

```
class Database {
    constructor(data: Buffer);
    constructor(data: Uint8Array);
    constructor(data: number[]);

    run(sql: string): Database;
    ...
}
```

How to instanciate empty db object? What are these parameters in constructor overrides used for?

Comment: Fixed. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8c6386ebf41ab6f7f6ce40f1456325ee036b55b9/sql.js/sql.js.d.ts

Comment: also played with it here: https://github.com/projectje/sqljs-wrapper-cogmios

Answer (score 1):

No sure, why there is no constructor() in Database class of sql.js typing, but this way works fine for me:

```
    var buffer: Buffer;
    var db = new sql.Database(buffer);
    db.run("CREATE TABLE snapshots (dateTime LONGINT, snapshot BLOB)");
```

Although buffer variable is not defined, db object is instanciated.